# Appium: How to launch an app without login

Tags: appium

I have set of multiple test cases. In first test case, I want to login and after that for subsequent test cases I want my driver to start the activity for home screen. But I am getting an error:

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent**

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Set these capabilities in your android desired capabilities

`capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","activityName");  capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");`

For your reference : http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/